# Create a failover server, with all configuration files and everything from master server

Tags: linux, server, backup, rsync, ispconfig

I have a primary server, where I'm running couple off websites. 
A friend of mine has configured everything there. Im running Debian on my server.

ISPConfig (Where I manage all my domains, mails, ftp) 
Apache
Mysql
PHPMyadmin

Now, I have very important websites which needs to up and running all the time and I want to purchase another server so if this one fails the other one should take over. 
I'm planning to use DNSMadeEasy service..

I know I can use rcync to clone all of this but my question is:

How do I know what needs to be copied to the other files so I get all the configuration files of all different services i'm running. 
Is there a way to clone on server to another or what is the best approach here?

Im super concerned that this server might go do, and I can not afford to have my website going do.. 
Any thought and ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but here are a couple of basic technologies that you should consider:

(1)  Set up another MySQL server which is a *replication slave* of the master.  The two servers communicate so that the slave is always up-to-date.

(2)  Use version control such as `git` to manage all the software that is installed on any server, and all versions and changes made to it.  `commit` the changes as they are made and push the changes to an independent "repository," e.g. on *(a private repository on a ...)* public service such as GitHub or BitBucket.

(3)  Arrange for all "asset files" to be similarly-maintained this time probably using rsync.